# ScalaTest w/ Selenium: running close() after all tests have run/completed

Tags: scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scalatest

I have a few scala tests up and running but am confused as to how to close/quit webdriver upon completion of the run. I am aware of beforeAndAfterAll, but it seems that it acts on each test class whereas I only want to quit webdriver at the end (not inbetween each test & then restarting it). It doesn't appear to be doing anything, but here's what I've currently got:

```
class testRunHandler extends org.scalatest.Reporter{
    import org.scalatest.events._
    def apply(event: Event){
      event match{
        case _:RunCompleted => foo.driver.close()
        case _ =>
      }
    }
```

I tried to follow this but wasn't sure how to apply it: 
[Doing something before or after all Scalatest tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423337/doing-something-before-or-after-all-scalatest-tests)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
sys.addShutdownHook { foo.driver.close() }
```

It's probably best if you make sure this line is only executed once. I've put in an `object`, near where I configure the driver.